# jQuery fails to send arrays as JSON content type

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I'm using a script that looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myservice',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: ["test"],
});
```

However this causes a request to `myservice/?undefined=undefined` which probably indicates that jQuery is assuming data to be a map. Is there any way around this? Is there a way to serialize data manually (preferably without resorting to any 3rd party libraries)?

I tested my service manually and it works correctly with the data like `["test"]`.

EDIT: A bug concerning request method.

EDIT(2): Interesting, now it causes `400 Bad request`. However if I switch to `'["test"]'` (a string) it works. I use jQuery 1.5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myservice',
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: '["test"]',
});
```

Note that you need to pass in the json as a string.

If your json is complicated you can always use Crockford's [stringify](http://json.org/js.html).

Comment: If `data` is not a string, jQuery will convert it.

Comment: I don't think that applies to json, adam. Please provide me an example / reference. I just tried this.

Comment: Interesting - I was going on my understanding of it. From the jQuery description of data at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ - "It is converted to a query string, if not already a string". If the json data is a string, surely jQuery would need to convert it to an object to then convert it to a query string (or other type)?

Comment: It works with an object if you want the data sent as regular name value pairs.

Answer (score 4):

change `method: 'POST'` to `type: 'POST'`

[doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) | [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jHBL5/)

Edit: for `data` you should use either query string `example=test&examplex=test2` or javascript object `{example: "test", examplex: "test2"}`

Comment: I changed it and now it causes BAD REQUEST (see my edit). I guess I have to convert it manually. Note: the service supports both GET and POST, so the problem wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

data should be an object like:

```
{var1: 'test', var2: 'test'}
```

Also, I think you can make your contentType just: 'json'

If you need to serialize a form and send in the values, jQuery has a function for that:

```
$("formId").serialize();
```

see [This Link](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: Well the point is that it cannot be of this format as another format is required on the server side. My understanding is that `["test"]` is valid JSON, or am I wrong?

Comment: The data is supplied manually, it doesn't come from a form. Also `serialize()` produces `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: jQuery data needs to be an object (as El Guapo says), but will be converted to the content type specified in `content` - which, as above, should be 'json'

Comment: Yes, it is valid notation for an array with 1 value ("test")... either way... if you don't pass in a true querystring, jQuery will attempt to create it for you...

Comment: Specifying `contentType: 'json'` causes `UNSUPPORTED MEDIA TYPE`.